# Recover Password of my keystore

Tags: android, passwords, keystore

I lost my keystore's password. I downloaded a jar library fallowing address.
http://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wiki/HowTo

But this application search every target. I know, my password is 13 character and i didn't use special character.

Is there any way to find it?

Comment: Even 13 characters of lowercase only would be a massive search, I put it at about 40 years odd average if you could check a billion keys a second

Comment: All my character is lowercase and I don't use special character. just just digit and letter.

Comment: Well if you add numbers in the mix as well, above estimate goes to 2500 years average (over 5000 to search entire space)

Comment: Nope, 3 decimal digits have 1000 combinations, type 10 ^ 3 into Google for example. Now try the same with 36 ^ 13 / 1000000000 / 365 / 86400. That is 36 (26 characters + 10 numeric) raised to 13 for the digits divided by a billion divided by rough days per year divides by seconds per day.

Comment: then there is not any solition is it?

Comment: Not really using a brute force approach, maybe if you're in the habit of using dictionary words plus a few numbers on the end you could work it out, but if it was just something fairly random I can't really think of a way.

Comment: i created my keys and i figured out my problem. thank you PeterJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments of your original question, it's probably going to take a while.

I have also made a keystore bruteforce program, with which you can configure what characters you want to use to search.

You can get the source from here and modify as you like: https://github.com/bes/KeystoreBrute

Change the constructor of this file for limiting the characters used in your search https://github.com/bes/KeystoreBrute/blob/master/src/se/bes/br/Breaker.java

The less characters you use, the faster it's going to go.

I would also suggest that you use a startdepth of 13, since you know how long the password is.

Happy hunting!

Answer (score 0):

**2018 LATEST WORKING ANSWER**

Search for folder  **.gradle**

under it go to latest folder in my case it is **4.6**

go to **taskHistory** folder

under it open **taskHistory.bin** file

search for **Password** keyword in that file

and you will eventually find your stored password for that keystore file.

refer the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: android studio give me password when i create a release. but i forgot the jks file password. I also search on executionHistory.bin in latest android studio and gradle version 7.0.2 but i think the password is encryted and android studio does not return.please help me how to recover password